# Авторизация php js 

Tags: ajax, php, form, авторизация

Добрый День. Такой вот вопрос.. мучаюсь уже долго. Есть html страница с формой авторизации:

```
<div id = "authForm" class="auth">

        <div id="authup">
            <form id="nosubmitform" class="outer-shadow1">
            <fieldset>

            <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>

            Логин:<br />
            <input type = "text" name = "login" id="authLogin" placeholder = "Введите Логин" pattern=".{3,}" placeholder="Минимум 3 символа" title="Минимум 3 символа" required="" />
            <p class="validation01">
                        <span class="invalid">Минимум 3 символа</span>
                        <span class="valid">Логин введен корректно</span>
            </p>
            <br />
            <br />
            Пароль:<br />
            <input type = "password" name = "password" id="authPassword" placeholder = "Введите Пароль" title="Минимум 5 символов" pattern="(?=^.{5,}$)(?![.\n]).*" required=""/>
            <p class="validation02">
                        <span class="invalid">Минимум 5 символов</span>
                        <span class="valid">Пароль введен корректно</span>
            </p>

            </fieldset>

            <input type = "submit" name = "submit_auth" id = "submit_auth" value="ВОЙТИ НА САЙТ"> 
            </form></br>
            <div align="right"><a href="#res" style="text-decoration: none; color: white">Забыли пароль?</a>
            </div>
            <div id = "authMessages">

            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Есть также скрипт авторизации:

```
<?php
    session_start();

    require_once "functions.php";

    /* Получаем и обрабатываем данные */
    $login = escape($_POST['login']);
    if (strlen($login) == 0) exit;
    $password = escape($_POST['password']);
    if (strlen($password) == 0) exit;

    $password_hash = md5($password.$hash); // Создаём хеш пароля

    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `login` = '$login' AND `password` = '$password_hash'");

    if ($result) {
        $arr = $result->fetch_assoc();
        if ($arr['password'] != $password_hash) $auth = 1;
        if ($arr['login'] == $login && $arr['password'] == $password_hash) {
            $_SESSION['user'] = $arr['login'];
            $auth = $arr['login'];
        }
echo '<span>Ошибка! 
<br><form action="/#regForm">
<input type=button onclick="window.location.reload()" id="return" type="submit" value="ЗАЙТИ СНОВА">
</form></center></div>';
    }
    else
        $auth = 2;
?>
```

И сам js скрипт:

```
$(function() {

$("#nosubmitform").submit(function() {
   return false;
});

$('#submit_auth').click(function() {
    var login = $('#authLogin').val();
    var password = $('#authPassword').val();
    if (login == '' || password == '') {

    }
    else 
    {
        $.ajax({
            url:        'auth.php',
            type:       'POST',
            cache:      false,
            data:       {'login':login, 'password':password},
            dataType:   'html',
            success: function(data) {
                $('#authMessages').html(data);
                if (data == 1) $('#authMessages').show();
                if (data == 2) {
                    location.reload();
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Однако - если в моем предыдущем вопросе про форму - что если есть форма - то она просто обновляется при нажатии кнопки submit - помогло решение в виде добавления функции

```
{
$("#nosubmitform").submit(function() {
   return false;
});
```

То здесь - форма все равно обновляется при введении данных, не содержащихся в базе. Если ввести правильный логин и пароль - то все гуд. Авторизация проходит успешно. 
Что можно предпринять, чтобы форма не обновлялась - а хотя бы писала ошибку? Если тег <form> убрать - то пишется ошибка, как и должно быть. Но хотелось бы все-таки оставить форму авторизации.

Спасибо за ответы!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не уверен, что понял суть вопроса, но попробуйте

```
$("#nosubmitform", "#submit_auth").submit(function() {
   return false;
});
```

Comment: Спасибо. Действительно работает. Хотя я вот как решил эту проблему:
Добавил вот эту строчку:
$("#nosubmitform1").submit(function(e) { e.preventDefault();
вместо $('#submit_auth').click(function() {
Так как у меня для #submit_reg - уже стоит:
$("#nosubmitform").submit(function(e) { e.preventDefault();

Причем если вместо #submit_reg - поставить тоже #nosubmitform, то ничего не работает. Поэтому пришлось форму для авторизации обозвать как nosubmitform1.

Answer (score 1):

Почему не:

```
<button type="button" id="submit_auth">Войти</button>
```

и

```
$('#submit_auth').click( function() {
   // получить данные формы
   // отправить на сервер
});
```

`type="submit"` пытается отправить данные формы, и обновляет страницу.

`type="button"` просто кнопка

в таком случае, даже `<form>` не нужен

Answer (score 0):

Пользуясь ответом dy_ma, могу дополнить то, что Вы можете использовать функцию `$('form').serialization();` для сбора всех данных с формы и отправки их на валидацию с помощью jQuery без перезагрузки страницы:

```js
function loginUser(){
  var u_data = $('form').serialize();
  $('#result').html('Данные (POST или GET) которые передаються с помощью AJAX :<br>' + u_data);
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="text" name="login" placeholder="Username">
  <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password">
  <button type="button" onclick="loginUser()">Login</button>
</form>
<div id="result"></div>
```

А там уже можете делать с данными что хотите.

Вот сама отправка данных на скрипт:

```
$.ajax({
  type : "POST|GET",
  url : "script.php",
  data : $('form').serialize(),
  success : function(response){ //Обработка ответа 'response' },
  progress : //Действие, которое происходит во время работы скрипта
});
```